# Using Mercurial, can I push changes to another repo w/o doing commits?

Tags: mercurial

I have two repos on separate machines, one cloned from the other. One of the machines is a VM, which offers little desktop space and tools. So I'd like to know if I can make changes in the repo on my main box, and somehow push them over to the other repo where I build and test, but without doing any commits, otherwise I'd have tons of useless commits. And only once I have a tested change on the VM would I then do a commit to the local repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can make temporary commits on your local repository, push them to the [non-publishing](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository) VM repo, then fold them together using [`hg histedit`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) once you're satisfied they basically work.  You'll end up with as many or as few commits as you like.

Comment: Though unless he strips them from the other repo, he'll have both the squashed changeset(s) and the original standalone changesets there.

Comment: This is true, for now, but eventually `hg evolve` will eliminate that problem.